# When does transaction start in controllers update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my order's controller, I'm doing a change to another object, prior to updating the order's attributes, like

```
def update
  @order.organisation.something = @order.something
  @order.organisation.save!

  if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
    redirect_to @order
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Reason is I need the order's previous value (here called "something") to update the organisation before the order receives its new value

I would expect, when the update_attributes faults due to invalid attributes, that also the changes to the organisation would be rolled back, which apparently isn't the case. So my question is: why is this change not part of the "implicit" transaction? And how can I make it part of it?

Comment: why are you saving @order.organisation? Just use \@order.organisation.something = \@order.something and rails will automatically save organisation after saving @order.

Comment: I must say I wasn't aware of that... (pretty new on rails) Any suggested reading on this? I thought (read) that the controller started one implicit transaction, which covered all database changes. Not true?

Comment: is this due to "autosave associations"?

Comment: No, rails do not start any implicit transaction for any action of the controller.

Comment: I pre-assumed that you have used autosave option to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that you are coming from java and have made extensive use of transactions to manage state on server side.

rails is very different in this regard. it only runs transactions when it updates data. so a call to `create` or `save` or `update_attributes` will be a single transaction and you have to handle transactions yourself if you want to group statements.

i once created [a gem called active_service](https://github.com/phoet/active_service) to help with this functionality, but i think it's just to bloated for general purpose rails programming. however, it shows how to handle transactions yourself in rails.

it's actually pretty simple, you can just call `transaction` on every `ActiveRecord` class:

```
User.transaction { [your transactional code here] }
```

Comment: I started reading about this, and, to summarize, I understand that a save or create starts a transaction, so all object modifications in callbacks from this save or create are handled in that transaction. If I need more, I have to explicitly start a transaction myself. Good summary?

Comment: that summarizes it quite well.